How to phrase the proof of $m \lt n$ if and only if $m \le n-1$
I have been reading Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming" and in the mathematical preliminaries chapter of volume 1 there is on page 476 the answer to an exercise where he states

... the fact that when m and n are integers
we have $m \lt n$ if and only if $m \le n-1$ ...

Should I take that as an axiom or is there a way to phrase a proof to that statement of "fact" ?
I would be content with some reference to what math topics to research so that I could find proofs to that statement of fact if there are such proofs.
Also excuse me if the tags of my question are not chosen as good as they could be, someone might modify my question to change the tags to more appropriate ones.

Since Knuth doesn't seem to define $\Bbb Z$, and $<$ and $\le$ on it, it really depends on how you do.

In fact "$m < n \Leftrightarrow m \leq n - 1$" is a perfectly suitable definition of $<$ for the integers.

Indeed, or of $\le$. But one can also imagine to define each independently, and then prove Knuth's "fact".

It's certainly not an axiom but it is so intuitively obvious that the author maybe didn't think it needed proving.  To prove it... well, that depends on your definitions and axioms but essentially you should be proven or had as an axiom either there is no integer between $0$ and $1$ and/or that there are no integers between an integer and its successor.  This result can follow from that by a proof by contradiction.  (If $m<1$ and it is not true that $m\le n-1$ then $n-1 < m < n$ [and maybe $0 < m-(n-1) < 1$] which are contradictions.)

As commented, there are many ways to answer your question. Mine would be to define $(\Bbb N,0,S)$ by Peano axioms, then $+$ on $\Bbb N$, then $(\Bbb Z,+)$ as a quotient of $(\Bbb N\times\Bbb N,+)$, and finally (after embedding naturally $\Bbb N$ into $\Bbb Z$): $\forall m,n\in\Bbb Z$: $$m\le n\iff\exists k\in\Bbb N,n=m+k$$ and $$m<n\iff m\le n\text{ and }m\ne n.$$
Then, prove that $(\Bbb Z,+)$ is cancellative, hence $m<n\iff\exists k\in\Bbb N\setminus\{0\},n=m+k$. Derive also from Peano axioms that $\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}=\Bbb N+1$. This allows to conclude:
$$\begin{align}m<n&\iff\exists j\in\Bbb N,n=m+j+1\\&\iff\exists j\in\Bbb N,n-1=m+j\\
&\iff m\le n-1.
\end{align}$$

Within the Context of TAOCP , it is just some "Heuristic" which the readers should know "Intuitively" , not Axiom or Theorem. It is implied by the usage of the term "fact" & the informal way Natural Numbers are introduced.
Here , after the Discussion , I give a Proof using Axioms + Definitions.
DISCUSSION :
OP : Should I take that as an axiom or is there a way to phrase a proof to that statement of "fact" ?
Knuth uses informal ways to talk about Natural Numbers & Integers , where the readers are supposed to have some "Prior Intuition" about such things.
Knuth says "The reader may choose to read the following subsections carefully, with implicit faith in the author's assertion that the topics treated here are indeed very relevant; [...] If too much time is spent studying this material when first reading the book, a person might never get on to the computer programming topics!"
Clearly , this is not Axiomatic Math here & that "fact" is not "Axiom" with TAOCP. There is no way to Prove that formally , because there are no Axioms to use.
Even Induction is introduced as just some useful tool , whereas it is the Core Basis for "Definition of Natural Numbers" & not some external tool.
OP : I would be content with some reference
Knuth adds "... more leisurely presentation of much of the following material can be found in the book Concrete Mathematics by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik ..." , though that is even more informal.
Suggestion from me would be Terrence Tao "Analysis" which is a great modern readable reference.

Tao lists the Axioms to make the Natural Numbers , makes useful Definitions , uses that to generate various Theorems & then gives "Exactly" what you are looking for via "Proposition 2.2.12 (Basic properties of order for natural numbers)" & other stuff like Trichotomy , all that within 20 Pages !!
Specifically, (e) will match your requirement & (f) will extend it.
Proofs using this formal Axiomatic treatment allows us to go deeper into the "heuristic fact" given by Knuth.
I will rephrase (e) , since OP might not have come across $++$ & such.
(e) $a \lt b$ if and only if $a+1 \le b$ : that can be rewritten like $a \le b-1$ later , hence we get what Knuth wrote : $m \lt n$ if and only if $m \le n-1$
Proof :
With the Axiomatic treatment given by Tao , this will work :
$x \lt y \implies x+D=y$ where $D$ is a Natural Number and $D$ is not $0$.
$x \le y \implies x+D=y$ where $D$ is a Natural Number and $D$ might or might not be $0$.
Now , we are given $m \lt n$ which gives $m+D=n$ , where $D$ is not $0$.
Hence , we have $m+D-1=n-1$ , where $D-1$ is a Natural Number , which might or might not be $0$.
Hence , we have $m \le n-1$ , which is what we want !
We can work this in reverse too. Hence the two are Equivalent.

Note: I didn't intend to "correct" Knuth or anything like that. Knuth is a god of computer science. In the context of TAOCP having the relation as an axiom is perfectly fine. It's about programming, not pulling all of math foundations in the context of a programming book. It's just that I wanted more than can fit in 40 pages of basic math to study algorithms. And I am getting all I wanted from the community here :) . Thanks for your answer.

Knuth makes it very clear that Axiomatic Math is not the focus. Computer Programming + Algorithms may be analyzed , @branco , with Heuristic Concepts used informally , which is enough at that level.

Were you able to check out that Axiomatic Proof I gave there ? Do let me know , @branco , whether Details and Clarifications are required.

Sorry we may have a different definition of what axioms mean in math. I just adopted my meaning of axiom in math to be aligned with what the physicist Richard Feynman said in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obCjODeoLVw.

Regarding studying what you replied: I'll do it in due time.

With peano postulates I'd say (this is an outline)
The induction postulate implies that there can be no natural number between $0$ and $1$.  (Else induction would only work on $0$ and the successor of $0$ and the successors of those but not on any of the natural numbers between $0$ and $1$).
The induction postulate can be used to prove the well-ordering principal [that for any non-empty set of natural numbers there is always a least element].
Suppose there were a natural number $k$ so that there exists a number $n_k$ where $n_k < k < n_k +1$.  $n_k \ne 0$ (because there is no natural number between $0$ and $1$) so then $n_k -1, k-1$ are also integer and $n_k < k-1 < n_k$.  and $k-1 < k$.  So $k$ can't be the smallest such number and there can't be any smallest such number.  So there can't be any integer but any $n$ and $n+1$.
That was for natural numbers.  We can extend it to negative integers but expanding the definition of negatives.  ($m < n < m+1 \le 0 \iff 0 \le -m-1 < -n < -m =(-m-1)+1$ so as the RHS is impossible so is the LHS.)
Okay.  If $m \le n-1$ then $n-1 < n$ so $m < n$.   And if $m< n$ then if $m \not \le n-1$ then $m > n-1$ so $n-1 < m < n$.  But there is no such $m$ so $m < n$ and $m \not \le n-1$ is impossible.
